# Delete an item from DictRow

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there a clean way to delete an item (both its value and index) from a `psycopg2` `DictRow` object?

I am using `psycopg2` to interact with two different postgresql databases. I want to copy a record as a DictRow from one database to the other - *and* I want to delete a couple of fields from the records before inserting them.

For example, if I have a DictRow called `row`:

```
>>> print row
[12, '2015-12-31', 'kefir sriracha put a bird on it']

>>> print row.keys()
['id', 'created_at', 'output_example']
```

Using `row.pop(INDEX)` changes the indices of the list, so the keys stored in the `row._index` attribute are no longer correct!

```
>>> row.pop(0)
12

>>> print row
['2015-12-31', 'kefir sriracha put a bird on it']

>>> print row.keys()
['id', 'created_at', 'output_example']

>>> print row['id']
'2015-12-31' # GAAAAA!!!
```

You can't use use `del row['id']`: `TypeError`. I presume this is because the underlying object is a `list` and expects an integer index.

My current workaround is to do something like this, which seems inelegant:

```
fields = [f for f in row.keys() if f != 'id']
values = [v for k, v in row.iteritems() if k != 'id']
```

Any suggestions for a more direct way of deleting an item from a DictRow?

Comment: how can you use row.keys()? isn't "row" a list as in your example?

Comment: It looks like a completely wrong approach. Could you explain why you you need to make the journey to Python and back to Postgresql?

Comment: @kmario23: It's an object based on list, but it's a `DictRow`: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I'm doing some other things within that script for which I need python. I hear what you're saying - it'd be cleaner to do this part in postgresql.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`RealDictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor)

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
query = """select 1 as one, 2 as two"""
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()
d = rs[0]
print d
del(d['one'])
print d
```

Output:

```
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
{'two': 2}
```

Comment: I'd have to refactor a bunch of code that relies on the DictCursor, so I'm reluctant to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have been using for this is to take the `DictRow` and convert it to a `dict`.

```
my_row = dict(row.items())
del my_row['id']

fields = my_row.keys()
values = my_row.values()
```

It does change the data type, so it's not a great answer to the question I posed. In this specific case, it was easier than refactoring other code that relies on the same cursor and its behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Example: (under psycopg2==2.8.4, python 3.7)

(You probably solved the issue already, but I'm posting in case other people need this.)

```
# We want to exclude column 'a' in row.
row: DictRow
# row = {'a': value1, 'b': value2}
# row._index = OrderedDict({'a': 0, 'b': 1})

remove_columns = ['a']
remove_columns_index_set = set()
# Find the index of the column to exclude. a -> 0.
for col in remove_columns:
  remove_columns_index_set.add(row._index.get(col))

# Override the list with new values. (I find this line in DictRow's __init__)
row[:] = [col for idx, col in enumerate(row) if idx not in remove_columns_index_set]

# Delete the index of removed column.
# Because _index in row is shared among all rows, we only need to update it once.
for remove_col in remove_columns:
  del row._index[remove_col]

# Update the DictRow index to new value.
for idx, column in enumerate(row._index):
  row._index[column] = idx
```

I was looking for the same issue.

Had the impulse to include and rewrite DictRow in my codebase :)

Comment: Yeah, I copied/learned/stole lots of code from the community :)